# How to login as a different bash user in terminal?

Tags: macos

I have to check if my web page running locally on nginx does not work due to permission issue. My web scripts are running as `_www` user, so I tried to switch to `_www` but this does not work:

```
maciek@macus:~$ sudo su - _www
Password:
maciek@macus:~$ whoami
maciek
```

How can I do this in 10.8.5?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `sudo` is failing because the `_www` user has `/usr/bin/false` as its shell, causing the session to end as soon as you've switched user.

The solution is to use the `-s` option, which will execute your current shell instead of `_www`'s shell:

```
$ sudo -s -u _www
Password:
$ whoami
_www
```

Just tested on a 10.9 system but it should work fine on 10.8.

Comment: normal users should not use `sudo`.

Comment: @CousinCocaine define normal? are we normal?

Answer (score 22):

Use `login`:

```
$ login
login: username
Password:
Last login: Day Month Date HH:MM:SS on ttys000
$ whoami
username
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think that system users have passwords. It prompts for password, and empty does not work.

Comment: this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: As the OP commented, this won't work for users that don't have passwords (which the `_www` user won't have by default, nor should it have one).

Comment: This solved an issue I was having when using `nano` after using `su - username` to switch users in Terminal. The window would get garbled when changing window size while in nano. Thank you for this-- I've been looking for a solution for days.