# Command not found: /usr/local/bin/zsh

Tags: terminal, homebrew, iterm, path, zsh

I uninstall homebrew on a Mac Mini M1 to reinstall it.

After opening a terminal to run the install shell script, the terminal produces the following output and becomes unusable.

```
[Command not found: /usr/local/bin/zsh]

[Could not create a new process and open a pseudo-tty.]
```

I have logged into recovery mode and attempted to reset the path with:

```
mount -uw /         
ln -s /usr/local/bin/zsh /usr/bin/
```

then comming back and trying again without success.

I was directed to this channel in the comments at https://stackoverflow.com/q/70522270/2336356 where it is suggested I open a new terminal and make some changes:

> You either changed your login shell to /usr/local/bin/zsh, or configured your default Terminal profile to start /usr/local/bi/zsh instead of your login shell. In either case, you can tell Terminal which process to run in a new terminal window.

However, any terminal I open, whether, iterm of kitty, for example, exit the process immediately after opening. This behavior started at the same time.

This has happened once before on an Intel Mac and I was able to fix it by logging into another admin user which had been set up in case something crazy like this happened. I cant seem to work it out this time.

Any guidance on a solution would be greatly appreciated.

### Update

Here is a different error pointing to the same issue in the default terminal:

> Last login: Wed Dec 29 19:09:59 on ttys001
> login: /usr/local/bin/zsh: No such file or directory

[Process completed]

I then came across this issue https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/126303/174950 and switched to a different user and was able to `cat /etc/shells` as the affected user:

```sh
# List of acceptable shells for chpass(1).
# Ftpd will not allow users to connect who are not using
# one of these shells.

/bin/bash
/bin/csh
/bin/dash
/bin/ksh
/bin/sh
/bin/tcsh
/bin/zsh
/usr/local/bin/fish
/usr/local/bin/pwsh
/usr/local/bin/zsh
```

I removed `/usr/local/bin/zsh` and now have:

```sh
/bin/bash
/bin/csh
/bin/dash
/bin/ksh
/bin/sh
/bin/tcsh
/bin/zsh
/usr/local/bin/fish
/usr/local/bin/pwsh
```

Still not working. Maybe I need to remove the `ln -s /usr/local/bin/zsh /usr/bin/` symlink executed earlier?

Comment: Homebrew on a M1 is not in /usr/local - basically solution is remove all /usr/local entries for /etc/shells The read homebrew documents on where the path is. Also why use a zsh in /usr/local why not just use the Apple supplied one

Comment: You can temporarily select a different shell in the Terminal application's preferences. Not in a Terminal window -- that's not working, but under the Terminal menu > Preferences. See [my answer to this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1689620/accidentally-deleted-fish-while-it-was-being-set-as-my-shell-what-can-i-do) for details. Once you have it functioning, you can either use chsh to change it permanently (and remove the Terminal prefs override), or reinstall /usr/local/bin/zsh (and remove the Terminal prefs override).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Homebrew installs programs under `/usr/local` on intel but under `/opt/homebrew` on arm. So once you've installed Homebrew's zsh, it will be at `/opt/homebrew/bin/zsh`. The zsh that ships with macOS is at `/bin/zsh`.

If you've hard-coded the path `/usr/local/bin/zsh` somewhere, you can use one of the following commands to make that exist:

```
sudo ln -s /bin/zsh /usr/local/bin
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/zsh /usr/local/bin
```

Your attempt with `ln` didn't work because you passed the arguments to `ln` in the wrong order, and also because the preinstalled zsh is in `/bin` and not `/usr/bin`.

If you want to change your login shell, you can use the following command:

```
chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

Or `chsh -s /opt/homebrew/bin/zsh` to change to Homebrew's zsh.

Modern macOS comes with a recent version of zsh, so there's no advantage to using the one from Homebrew. It's not like bash where macOS ships only an ancient version.

Comment: I got my shell back with `chsh -s /bin/zsh` from the other user. Thank you for this very excellent answer. I should have asked 5 hours ago.