# Create a user and switch to it from the command line in macOS

Tags: command-line, user-account, sonoma

Following [Can user accounts be managed via the command line?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4814/can-user-accounts-be-managed-via-the-command-line/4981#4981), I did:

`sudo dscl localhost -create /Local/Default/Users/myuid`

Then following [How to login as a different bash user in terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126302/how-to-login-as-a-different-bash-user-in-terminal), I did:

`sudo -s -u myuid` but only get:

`sudo: unknown user myuid`

Then I checked Fast User Switching in System Settings, and found that the

"Show in Control Center" is greyed out and cannot be selected

[image]

Comment: Did you only run this one command to create the new user or all of them (as listed in the Q&A you link to).

Comment: Yeah, now I've run all of them, on one line though, but the
"Show in Control Center" is still greyed out